# Suppose that a and b are integers, a $\equiv$ 11 (mod 19) and b $\equiv$ 3 (mod 19). Find the integer c such that c $\equiv$ a - b (mod 19).

Tags: modular-arithmetic

With $0 \le c \le 18$.

I can recall the basic modulo arithmetic properties, but I can't see how to apply them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is this question from? What have you tried so far yourself?

Comment: See the Congruence Sum, Product, and Polynomial Rules in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1):

$$a\equiv11\bmod(19)\\b\equiv3\bmod(19)\\\Rightarrow a-b\equiv8\bmod(19)\Rightarrow c\equiv8\bmod(19)$$

So c is any number of the form 19k+8

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)